# How to build java hidl client using gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I want to build a java hidl client.

It compiles and work well using mmm and Android.mk.
Now I want to build it thanks to gradle.

As told here: https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl-java/ I managed to import android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar lib in my gradle.build.
(for this I copied android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar in my package and added a dependency to it: dependencies {compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')}).

But then I'm stuck importing the android.os.IHwInterface, IHwBinder and HwBinder classes. They can be found there: frameworks/base/core/java/android/os. Should I also add framework.jar to my package?

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to include framework.jar also in the gradle file. But add it as `compileOnly` so that it won't be packaged with your application and increase the file size.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly files('libs/framework.jar')
}
```